# Can't edit GA setting for configuration file generation

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I'd like to change the tracking ID, but can't find how...

I clicked the `Get a configuration file` [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

[image]

Comment: can i use the same ID with different package.